# fgets doesn't work after scanf

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void delspace(char *str);

int main() {
    int i, loops;
    char s1[101], s2[101];

    scanf("%d", &loops);

    while (loops--) {
        fgets(s1, 101, stdin);
        fgets(s2, 101, stdin);
        s1[strlen(s1)] = '\0';
        s2[strlen(s2)] = '\0';

        if (s1[0] == '\n' && s2[0] == '\n') {
            printf("YES\n");
            continue;
        }

        delspace(s1);
        delspace(s2);

        for (i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++)
            s1[i] = tolower(s1[i]);

        for (i = 0; s2[i] != '\0'; i++)
            s2[i] = tolower(s2[i]);

        if (strcmp(s1, s2) == 0) {
            printf("YES\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("NO\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void delspace(char* str) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char sTmp[strlen(str)];

    while (str[i++] != '\0') {
        if (str[i] != ' ') {
            sTmp[j++] = str[i];
        }
    }
    sTmp[j] = '\0';
    strcpy(str, sTmp);
}
```

After I entered "loops", "s1" was assigned a blank line automatically. How does it happen? I'm sure my keyboard works fine.

Comment: "I'm sure my keyboard works fine." Lol!

Comment: Some variant of this question seems to be asked here every day or so.

Comment: The function `delspace` is definitely wrong! This will convert `abc\0` to `bc\0`.

Comment: Rule of thumb: for interactive input always read **lines**.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`scanf()` reads exactly what you asked it to, leaving the following `\n` from the end of that line in the buffer where `fgets()` will read it.  Either do something to consume the newline, or (my preferred solution) `fgets()` and then `sscanf()` from that string.

Comment: If I want to use `scanf()`, how I can consume the new line? Thanks.

Comment: Use something like `%*[^\n]%*c` at the end of the format to skip any characters up the newline, followed by the newline itself.

Comment: @geekosaur: Just tacking `%*[^\n]%*c` on to the end of the format won't actually work if there are NO characters after the previous thing read and before the newline, as then the `%*[^\n]` will fail to match so the `%*c` will be skipped and the newline will still be left on the input.  You need to do the `%*c` in a separate scanf call to make it work.

Answer (score 10):

`scanf` leaves whitespace in the input buffer, including new-line characters. To use fgets to read the next line you need to manually remove the rest of the current line:

```
int c;
do{
    c = getchar();
}while(c != EOF && c != '\n');
```

Comment: Yeah, that'll work too, but I personally just use fgets and then sscanf (as suggested by geekosaur) because it works "uniformly" for all sorts of data... not just single chars. And I like "generic, multi-purpose solutions". Cheers. Keith.

Comment: This does work for more then a character though - that's what the loop is for ;)

Answer (score 7):

This is a more Simpler solution

```
scanf("%d",&loops);
while ((getchar()) != '\n'); //This will consume the '\n' char
//now you're free to use fgets
fgets(string,sizeof(string),stdin);
```

Comment: `while ((getchar()) != '\n');` is an infinite loop on end-of-file.

Answer (score 1):

[Geekosaur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643977/geekosaur) has [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5918091/15168) your question well, I'm just pointing out another "problem" with your code.

The line `s1[strlen(s1)] = '\0';` is a [no-op](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) if `s1` is already properly null terminated BEFORE it executes.

But if `s1` is NOT already properly null-terminated BEFORE this line executes (and you're unlucky) it will cause:

- a [SIGSEGV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV) on a POSIX (*nix) system.
- a [GPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_protection_fault) on Windows.

This is because `strlen` basicaly finds the index of the **existing null-terminator** and returns it! Here's a valid, unoptimized implementation of strlen:

```
int strlen(char *string) {
    int i = 0;
    while(string[i] != '\0') {
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

So... If you're REALLY worried about strings NOT being null-terminated then you'd do something like:

- `string[sizeof(string)]='\0';` on *local* automatic strings (where the compiler "knows" the size of the string);
- or `string[SIZE_OF_STRING]` for all other strings, where `SIZE_OF_STRING` is (most commonly) a `#define`'d constant, or a variable which you maintain specifically to store the current-SIZE (not length) of a dynamically allocated string.

And if you're REALLY, REALLY, REALLY worried about strings not being null-terminated (like you're dealing with "dirty" libary methods (like Tuxedo's ATMI for example) you **ALSO** "clear" your "return strings" before passing them to the suspect library methods with:

- before:`memset(string, NULL, SIZE_OF_STRING);`
- invoke: `DirtyFunction(/*out*/string)`;
- after: `string[SIZE_OF_STRING]='\0'`

SIG11's are a complete biatch to find because (unless you "hook" them with a [signal-processor](http://users.actcom.co.il/%7Echoo/lupg/tutorials/signals/signals-programming.html) and say otherwise, they cause Unix to hard-terminate your program, so you can't log anything (after the fact) to help figure out where-in-the-hell-did-that-come-from... especially considering that in many cases the line of code which throws the SIG11 is no-where-near the actual cause of the string loosing its null-terminator.

Does that make sense to you?

PS: WARNING: `strncpy` does NOT always null terminate... you probably meant `strlcpy` instead. I learned this the hard way... when a 60 million dollar billing run crashed.

---

**EDIT:**

FYI: Here's a "safe" (unoptimized) version of strlen which I'll call `strnlen` (I reckon this should be in *string.h*. Sigh.).

```
// retuns the length of the string (capped at size-1)
int strnlen(char *string, int size) {
    int i = 0;
    while( i<size && string[i]!='\0' ) {
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: I am novice at C, and the textbook doesn't talk about string and security much. Maybe my textbook isn't good enough :( Thank you for your professional advice :)

Comment: Do not do `string[sizeof(string)]='\0'`! This will write write a `\0` AFTER the allocated memory! `sizeof(s1)` is 101 and the the index of s1 goes from 0 to 100! The same problem occurs with the `strnlen`. If there is no `\0` then it will return `size`, not `size - 1` as mentioned in the comment!

Answer (score -1):

Another way to ignore following newline character (due to hitting ENTER) after scanning the integer in variable label loops is:

```
scanf ("%d%*c", &loops);
```

Where, as per the man pages:

> *        Suppresses assignment.  The conversion that follows occurs as usual, but no pointer is used; the result of the conversion is simply discarded.

This is very unlikely, but good habit to check for error during scanf:

```
errno = 0
scanf ("%d%*c", &loops);
if (errno != 0) perror ("scanf");
// act accordingly to avoid un-necessary bug in the code
```

For example in your code, loops is a local un-initialized variable, containing garbage. If scanf fails to fill the desired value, following while loop may run arbitrarily.

Comment: That's not how you check errors from scanf

Answer (score -1):

`scanf()` leave the following \n from the end of that line in the buffer where `fgets()` will read it. To slove this we have to do something to consume the newline. Let's see the problem.

### The problem

```c
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char input[10];
    printf("Enter in fgets: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    getchar();
    printf("Enter in scanf: ");
    fgets(input, 10, stdin);
}
```

Output:

```
Enter in scanf: Hello
Enter in fgets:
```

As you can see that it dons't show the fgets part. Let's see the solution.

#### Put `getchar()` between scanf and `fgets()`

```c
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char input[10];
    printf("Enter in fgets: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    getchar();
    printf("Enter in scanf: ");
    fgets(input, 10, stdin);
}
```

Output:

```
Enter in scanf: Hello
Enter in fgets: Hello
```

#### If it's possible use `scanf()` after the `fgets()`

```c
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char input[10];
    printf("Enter in fgets: ");
    fgets(input, 10, stdin);
    getchar();
    printf("Enter in scanf: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
}
```

Output:

```
Enter in fgets: Hello
Enter in scanf: Hello
```

#### Put `fget()` 2 times(This method don't work some time)

```c
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char input[10];
    printf("Enter in fgets: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    getchar();
    printf("Enter in scanf: ");
    fgets(input, 10, stdin);
    fgets(input, 10, stdin)
}
```

Output:

```
Enter in scanf: Hello
Enter in fgets: Hello
```

#### Put `sscanf()` inseted of `scanf()`

```c
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char input[10];
    printf("Enter in fgets: ");
    sscanf(hello, "%s", input);
    getchar();
    printf("Enter in scanf: ");
    fgets(input, 10, stdin);
}
```

Output:

```
Enter in sscanf: Hello
Enter in fgets: Hello
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on this further? E.g. Providing an example.

Answer (score -2):

just put 
    `scanf("%d\n",&loops);`

instead of 
     `scanf("%d",&loops);`

Comment: While this answer covers an important phenomenon of the original problem, it fails to provide some insight into the problem itslef. Thus, it is helpfull at best to the exect original problem and not really helpful in the long run. Please, add some more explanation to make your answer helpful to later readers looking for similar problems.

Comment: Do not put trailing white space at the end of a `scanf()` format string — it completely breaks the UI/UX because the input doesn't stop until you type something other than white space (and newlines are white space).  It means the user has to predict what the next input needs to be.  See [What is the effect of trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19499060/10ths 5168)