# Detect a new line character

Tags: c

I am reading from stdin students in a structure array. After the details are introduced for one student, i ask for another student details. if the choice is Y, i'll add the new student, if the choice is N, break. But what if the choice is simply ENTER? How can i detect the new line character? I tried with getchar(), but it skips the first reading from stdin.When i debug it doesn't stops to the first line test=getchar(), it stops to the second one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
char name[20];
int age;
};

int main()
{
struct student NewStud[5];
char test;
int count=0;
for(count=0;count<5;count++)
{
    printf("Enter the details for %s student: ",count>0?"another":"a");
    printf("\nName : ");
    scanf("%s",NewStud[count].name);
    printf("\nAge : ");
    scanf("%d",&NewStud[count].age);
    printf("Would you like to continue? (Y/N)");
    test=getchar();
    if(test=='\n')
    {
        printf("Invalid input. Would you like to continue? (Y/N)");
        test=getchar();
    }
    while(tolower(test) !='n' && tolower(test) != 'y')
    {
        printf("Invalid input.Would you like to continue? (Y/N)");
        test=getchar();
    }
    if(tolower(test) == 'n')
    {
        break;
    }
    if(tolower(test) == 'y')
    {
        continue;
    }
}


getch();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like C++. In the future please tag either C or C++ as both languages can have a different style of accomplishing your task.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what your issues is. What exactly does "it skips the first reading from stdin" mean? (99% chance your issue is that someone types "Y enter" and you read only one character, leaving the enter to read the next time you call `getchar`. Use a function that reads lines.)

Comment: This looks like a homework question.  Homework questions get a homework tag.  I'm pretty sure it is, so I'll go ahead and add it for you.  If you disagree, you can remove it yourself.  Edit: uhh, obselete and in the process of being removed? *goes to meta*

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Laura can correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure the problem is that the prompts "...(Y/N)" is displayed and then it goes right away to the "Invalid input" message. Due to the '\n' being left on the input buffer because of the use of `scanf()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `scanf()` leaves a newline character in the input stream, you have to consume it before you'll get "valid" data in `getchar()`.

Ex:

```
scanf("\n%s",NewStud[count].name);
getchar();
printf("\nAge : ");     
scanf("%d",&NewStud[count].age);
getchar();
printf("Would you like to continue? (Y/N)");
test=getchar();   // Now this will work
```

Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf) for more info. It's for fgets, but it's the same problem with `getchar()`

Answer (score 0):

Compare `test` value with '\n', like this sample:

```
int main() {
    int test;
    test = getchar();
    printf("[%d]\n", test);
    if(test == '\n') printf("Enter pressed.\n");
    return(0);
}
```

ps: your `test` must be `int`.

Comment: getchar() returns a char, and since '\0' is a char there's no reason to use an int. OP wasn't saying her test was failing, just for the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Mike The `getchar()` from the C standard library returns an `int`. It can't return a `char` since it must be able to distinguish an `EOF` condition from a valid character.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it skips the first reading, you put it in an if statement like so: `if(test=='\n')`

You got all the info for that certain student and then the user pressed enter, so you go back up to `for(count=0;count<5;count++)` and ask for new input for a new student.
I think what you wanted to do is use a while statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace

```
> test=getchar();
>     if(test=='\n')
>     {
>         printf("Invalid input. Would you like to continue? (Y/N)");
>         test=getchar();
>     }
```

with

```
while((test=getchar()) == '\n')
{
  printf("Invalid input. Would you like to continue? (Y/N)");
}
```