# C Segmentation error when passing a file pointer to a method

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, compiler-construction, segmentation-fault

Everytime I try to do this I get a segmentation error. It's been really bothering me because this was a pretty difficult assignment and its late because I can't fix this one thing. I get a segmentation fault when I try to run parseInputStream. I've tried changing the file pointer to a pointer to a file pointer but I still get the segmentation fault. The console prints all of the ns but none of the ws. Help please.

```
void parseInputStream(FILE *file, FILE *infile){
    printf("w\n");
    char string[9999999];
    while(fscanf(infile, "%s", &string)!= EOF){
            printf("w\n");
            if(string[0] == ';'){
            fgets(string, 9999999, infile);
            continue;
            }
            parseInput(file, infile, string);
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("n\n");
    FILE *file = fopen("intest.asm", "w");
    printf("n\n");
    FILE *infile = fopen("intest.j", "r");
    printf("n\n");
    parseInputStream(file, infile);
    fclose(infile);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the stack maximum allowed size is usually around 8Mb in size, at least under a GNU/linux distribution, it may vary, but it's probably not gonna be that large.

Comment: Using `scanf` and `fgets` on the same stream is bound to [cause problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf). Also: you're passing `&infile` (a `FILE **`) to `fgets`, your compiler should be complaining about that.

Answer (score 3):

```
char string[9999999];
```

tries to declare just under 10Mb on the stack.  This is presumably too large and is causing your stack to overflow.

The easiest solution is to move `string` to another area of memory.  You could move it to have static duration:

```
static char string[9999999];
```

or you could allocate it dynamically:

```
char* string = malloc(9999999);
if (string==NULL) {
    // no memory, exit
}
// your code as before
free(string);
```

Also, as noted by Pyrce, allocating a 10 meg buffer like this is probably a bad sign.  If you need to read an entire file into memory, you could check its size first then allocate a buffer that is exactly the right size.  If you just want to read individual words, you can probably assume a smaller maximum and tell `fscanf` the size of your buffer to avoid any risk of writing beyond it

```
char string[100];
fscanf("%99s", string);
```

Comment: You might want to also mention that it's probably a bad design to allocate a 10MB buffer for loading an arbitrary file

Comment: Yea, that was it. In retrospect that was an awful idea. I just wanted to make sure the string was long enough to contain any comment, even unrealistically long ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are attempting to pass the address of infile to fgets.

fgets is defined as:

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

In your function parseInputStream infile is a stream.

```
void parseInputStream(FILE *file, FILE *infile){
```

Therefore you don't need to pass the reference to infile when you call fgets.

```
fgets(string, 9999999, &infile);
```

It should be:

```
fgets(string, 9999999, infile);
```

Comment: I was switching around all of the file pointers trying to fix the segmentation fault. This error was just me not being thorough when I  was putting my code back to the way it originally was submitted my question.