# Pointer unexplainably being Modified

Tags: c, pointers, input, struct

I have a pointer to a struct.

```
typedef struct anything{
    char text[MAXI];
    int any;
}Item;
```

After receiving the input in the struct, the program requests the user in which set he wants to store the struct.

```
void adding(){
    Item *x = malloc(sizeof(Item));
    printf("Enter an integer.");
    scanf("%d", (&x->any));
    printf("Enter a string.");
    scanf("%s", (&x->text));
    printf("Which set would you like to add the Item to A/B?");
    char inp1 = 0;
    while ((inp1=0),scanf("%s", &inp1) == 1 && (inp1 !=  'A') && (inp1 != 'B')){
        printf("Set does not exist\n");
    }
        if('A' == inp1)
            add(A, x);
        else
            add(B, x);

    flush();
    instructs();
}
```

When receiving the input (in the while loop), the pointer x is being modified from 0x570ff8 to 0x57f00, which will then point to garbage instead of the input requested below.

Why is the pointer being altered?

Thank you.

The add function:

```
void add(Array *S,Item *x){
    bool rep = false;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<=(S->size); i++){
        if(compStructs(*x,*(S->arr+i)))
            rep = true;
    }
    if(rep == false){
            x = realloc(S->arr, (S->size+1)*sizeof(Item));
            (S->size)++;
            printf("Item has been added");
    }
    else
        printf("The item is already in the set.");

}
```

Comment: `(inp1=0)` So when `(inp1=0)` will be `'A'`? Or is this modification not a single sequence?

Comment: Show the code for `add()`.

Comment: inp1 is being used to make sure that scanf reads 1 item. The inp1!= A and inp!= B are also used to notify the user whenever invalid input is entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
  char inp1 = 0;

  while ((inp1=0),scanf("%s", &inp1) == 1 && (inp1 !=  'A') && (inp1 != 'B'))...
```

You're using a string format specifier (`%s`) but reading into a char. Even if you just type a single character, `scanf` will be attempting to store a null-terminated string in the memory pointed to by `&inp1`.

This memory is on the stack - as is your pointer `x`. So `x`is probably being corrupted by the `scanf`. If you look at the change in value, you'll see the bottom byte of the address is zeroed. This could well be the null terminator being written.

To fix, change your `sscanf` to use a character format specifier:-

```
scanf("%c", &inp1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. A relatively small problem I'm getting now, is that the printf in the while loop is being accessed 1 time before the user is requested for his input. Also, when the user inputs an invalid input specified by the while loop, the printf is being printed 2 times.

Comment: @user2035045 - That will be because the first two `scanf`s leave a newline lurking in the input buffer. You could be better off using `fgets()`, then `sscanf`. See this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf

Answer (score 0):

One error is:

```
scanf("%s", (&x->text));
```

which should be

```
scanf("%s", x->text);
```

because `x->text` is already a pointer.

Another error is:

```
scanf("%s", &inp1)
```

which should be:

```
scanf("%c", &inp1)
```

because you are reading a single char.

Comment: I had previously used scanf("%s", (x->text)); but I was getting an SIGSEGV Segmentation Fault error.

Comment: @user2035045 what is MAXI?