# Why cant scanf read white spaces?

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

Why does scanf not read white spaces?

Also in my code if I use scanf first then fgets or scanf the second time after a few lines, as you can see in the code, then if I give an input that has a space like, "Hey How are u" then my code loops, why so?

I fixed it by just using fgets

```
while(1)
{
entry=&entry_var;
*entry=0;
printf("\n++++++++DFS CLIENT MENU++++++++");
printf("\n1-    ENTER THE COMMAND");
printf("\n2-    EXIT\n");
/*instance 1:if I use scanf here then whether i use scanf or fgets the
second time it loops in *entry==1 */
fgets (command, sizeof(command), stdin);
*entry=atoi(command);
printf("Entry: %d", *entry);
if(*entry==1)
{
    printf("\n--------COMMANDING ZONE--------");
    printf("\nInput the Function: ");
    //This is the second instance           
    fgets (command, sizeof(command), stdin);
    //scanf("%s",command);
    printf("\n%s",command);
    command_parse(command);
}
else if(*entry==2)
{
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: Erm ... because that is how it is specified?

Comment: [mixing fgets and scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf)

Comment: `scanf` is for reading and parsing tokens like numbers and words. Spaces are the separators between the tokens, it generally skips over them.

Comment: Thank you! I read the link that you posted, is there a way to empty this buffer? in the link it says scanf reads the string and leaves the \n in the buffer which causes the looping problem, so is there a command by which I can empty this buffer?

Comment: @AnuragAzad `while (getchar() != '\n');` should do it.

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read lines of data; use `sscanf()` when you want to parse the line of data.  It has many advantages, including that it avoids the problems you're running into.

Comment: @PC Luddite A weakness to `while (getchar() != '\n');` is that it is an infinite loop should `stdin` get closed.

Comment: @chux True, it was more of a guideline than an absolute.

Answer (score 1):

> Why cant scanf read white spaces?

This is a false question as `scanf()` *does* read white spaces.

`scanf()` reads from `stdin` and given various directives and specifiers, does its best to match them.  Some specifiers cause `scanf()` to save data.

`"%d"` specifies `scanf()` to:
1- Read and **discard all white-space**.
2- Read and covert numeric text into an `int`, saving the result into `i`.
3- Continue step 2 until reading a non-numeric character, which is returned to `stdin`.
4- Return 1 if step 2 successful.  Return 0 if step 2 only encountered non-numeric input.  Else return `EOF`.

```
int i;
if (1 == scanf("%d", &i)) GoodToGo();
```

All `scanf()` format specifiers except `"%c"`, `"%n"`, `"%[]"`, first read and discard leading white-space.

---

`"%c"` specifies `scanf()` to:
Read a `char` into `c`, **including any whitespace character**.
Return 1 or EOF.

```
char c;
if (1 == scanf("%c", &c)) GoodToGo();
```

`scanf()` and family details are beyond a simple answer here.  Check on-line resources for details.

---

Better to use `fgets()` to read a line than `scanf(any_format)`