# how to use both scanf and fgets to read a file

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

I need to read following text file:

```
2 2
Kauri tree
Waterfall
0 0 W S
0 1 E N
```

I wanted to use the `scanf` to get the first line and use the `fgets` for the second and the third line then use the `scanf` again for the rest of the lines.

I wrote the code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_OF_CHAR 2

int main()
{
    int node, edge;
    scanf("%d %d", &node, &edge);

    FILE* fp;
    fp = stdin;

    char* str[NUM_OF_CHAR];  //should be char str[NUM_OF_CHAR];

    for (int i = 0; i < node; i++) {
        fgets(str[i], 2, fp);     //should be fgets(str, 2, fp);
    }
    printf("%s", str[0]);         //printf("%s", str);
}
```

the input I entered was:

```
2 2
hello
```

I got `Segmentation fault`

I saw a similar question here, a person mentioned that I can call `fgets` once for getting the first line but ignore it and then use `fgets` again to get the second line. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Use fgets() and then strtok() to split the string up.

Comment: As for your *current* problem, the crash you get, now think a little. You declare an array of pointers to `char`, but you never make these pointers actually *point* anywhere.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for replying. I am new to c. I don't know how to use strtok(). I will look it up now.

Comment: You also have another problem, and that is that the first line you get with `fgets` (after you fix the pointer problem) will be *empty*. That's because the previous `scanf` didn't read the newline at the end of the previous line so `fgets` will see it as an empty line.

Comment: Hi Joachim. Thanks. I thought I used them in the for loop. How can I fix it?

Comment: Is it that after `scanf` read the first line, `fgets` will automatically read from the second line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fgets doesn't work after scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables defined inside functions will, unless explicitly initialized, have an *indeterminate* value. For pointers that means they are pointing at a seemingly random location. Using any uninitialized variable, except to initialize it, leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What happens here is that `fgets` will use the (uninitialized and seemingly random) pointer and use it to write into the memory it points to. This memory is in most cases not belonging to you or your program, and might even overwrite some other important data. This can lead to crashes, or other weird behavior or results.

The simplest solution is to make `str` an array of arrays of characters, like

```
#define NUM_OF_STRINGS 2
#define STRING_LENGTH 64
...
char str[NUM_OF_STRINGS][STRING_LENGTH];
...
fgets(str[i], sizeof str[i], stdin);
```

You need to make sure that `STRING_LENGTH` above is enough to fit every string *including* the newline and the string terminator. In the case of what I show above with it being `64` that means you can have lines of at most 62 characters.

---

Now as for the other problem I pointed out, with the first call to `fgets` reading an empty line.

If you have the input

```
2 2
hello
```

The input is stored in a buffer in memory, and then `scanf` and `fgets` reads from this buffer. The buffer will, with the above input, look something like this

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  2 |  2 | \n |  h |  e |  l |  l |  o | \n |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

After the `scanf` call read the two numbers the input buffer looks like

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| \n |  h |  e |  l |  l |  o | \n |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

So what the very first call to `fgets` in the loop will see is the newline. So it reads that newline and then it's done, leaving the string `"hello\n"` in the buffer for the *second* call to `fgets`.

There are a few ways to solve this problem. The one I personally prefer is to use `fgets` universally to read lines, and if you need a simple parsing of the line, then use `sscanf` (note the leading `s`, also please [see here for a good reference of all `scanf` variants](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)) to do so.

Another way is to simply read characters from the input, one character at a time, and discarding them. When you read a newline, stop the loop and continue with the rest of the program.

Comment: thanks. you have made it really easy to understand for me.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example, where comments explain some important points:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_OF_CHAR 2
#define LEN_OF_STR 20

int main()
{
    int node, edge;
    FILE* fp;
    fp = stdin;
    char strbuf[LEN_OF_STR];
    // stream is available after that
    // reading numbers
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &node, &edge);
    // reading strings
    for (int i = 0; i < node; i++) {
        // reading line from input stream
        fgets(strbuf, LEN_OF_STR, fp);
    }
    // cleaning input buffer
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    // reading lines with data
    char str[NUM_OF_CHAR];
    int a, b;
    for (int i = 0; i < node; i++) {
        // reading two numbers and two characters
        fscanf(fp, "%d %d %c %c", &a, &b, &str[0], &str[1]);
        // do something with dada, e.g. output
        printf("%d %d %c %c\n", a, b, str[0], str[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When you reading data with `scanf` or `fscanf` you can check results, e.g.:

```
    if (4 == fscanf(fp, "%d %d %c %c", &a, &b, &str[0], &str[1]))
    {
        // actions for correct data
    }
    else
    {
        // actions for wrong input
    }
```

here format line has 4 specifiers - "%d %d %c %c", so we check as "compare return value with 4"

Comment: Checking the return value of `scanf` is a *must*

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem. I should not use a `char*` pointer and make it point to an array. The first parameter that is passed to the `fgets` function supposed to be a `char*` so I should have used an array only.

also, since `scanf` scanned off the first line already, if I use `fgets` next, it will automatically get the next line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_OF_CHAR 100

int main()
{
    int node, edge;
    scanf("%d %d", &node, &edge);

    FILE* fp;
    fp = stdin;

    char str[NUM_OF_CHAR] = {'\0'};

    for (int i = 0; i < node; i++) {
        fgets(str, NUM_OF_CHAR, fp);
    }
    printf("%s", str);
}
```