# Loop doesn't work correctly (strings)

Tags: c, string, matrix

I'm writing a program that will sort words you input alphabetically, but I found it impossible to progress because the loop doesn't work as intended.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char string[50][50];
int i, n;

printf("Insert the number of strings: ");
scanf("%d ", &n);

for(i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Insert %d. string: ", i+1);
        fgets(string[i],50,stdin);
    }

return 0;
}
```

I tried using gets() and tried to use fgets(), but the result is the same. It prints:

```
Insert 1. string: Insert 2. string:
```

Then you can insert strings, but 1 less than specified.

Comment: Print `n`. What does it tell?

Comment: Remove semicolon after `for (i=0; i < n; i++);` Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Okay, I removed it but it still doesn't work. I know because I tried it in class and got the same results, didn't put a semicolon then.

Comment: Now this is probably a dup of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf I'd vote to close but already voted for a typo before the OP edited the post

Comment: But I didn't know what caused the problem. The semicolon was an oversight on my part.

Comment: That semicolon *was* the problem. You got an answer to that. It doesn't mean you can edit the post to ask a completely different question about a completely unrelated problem This is not how one conducts themselves on SO.

Comment: I'll just make the same thread, but now without the semicolon to get the answer to that.

Answer (score 3):

you have semicolon after for loop !!!