# fgets reads newline character from prompt

Tags: c, shell, fgets, stdio

I should mention that this *does* work in a different environment: in our programming class we normally use the IDE codeblocks (which is find awful), so I just use the gcc compiler and vim in my terminal (I'm on arch). I didn't encounter problems until recently, when I had to read in a string which contained spaces. For that I thought using the `fgets()` function would be a good idea, but it created some problems. This is what the code looks like:

```
void addStudent() {
    struct Student student;
    printf("Name of student: ");
    fgets(student.name, 25, stdin);
}
```

This however does not prompt me for input in my shell, it simply continues and reads in a newline character `\n` immediately. Do you guys have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Don't mix `scanf()` with `fgets()`. Preferably use only `fgets()` (possibly followed by `sscanf()`).

Comment: Did you use any input function somewhere before this? *Especially* something like `scanf`, perhaps?

Comment: Code presented is working as expected - the problem is likely elsewhere, which is why including a [mcve] is a good idea if you want an answer/solution to your problem

Comment: The problem is associated with whatever input is read BEFORE your function is called.    For example, if the last input is read using `scanf()`, a newline can be left in the input buffer, and immediately cause your call of `fgets()` to return.   The solution, in that case, is to be consistent with reading input - if using `fgets()` once to read from `stdin`, use `fgets()` EVERYWHERE to read from `stdin`.     More specific advice isn't possible since you haven't shown the preceeding code - you really need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Likely the explanation is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5918079/4386427

Comment: Okay so I understand that I shouldn't use `scanf()` since it messes with stdin, but which function should I use to read an integer from stdin?

Comment: @boston Use `fgets` to read a line into a buffer. Then use `sscanf` on that buffer.

Comment: Yeah that works! thanks guys

Comment: @boston See https://ideone.com/Bup77r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by the comments, it's not good to combine a function like `scanf()` with `fgets()`. When `scanf()` is called it leaves a newline character in the input buffer which is then immediately read by `fgets()`, causing it to fail prompting the user.