# Why is fgets() not taking input in C program?

Tags: c, fgets

I wrote a code to implement Julias Caesar Cryptography in **C**.

The problem is that my **fgets()** is not waiting for input and *skipping to fputs()*.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int size;
    printf("Enter the size of the string: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    int key;
    printf("Enter the key: ");
    scanf("%d",&key);

    char a[size];
    printf("Enter the string: ");
    fgets(a,size,stdin);

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        a[i]+=key;
    }

    fputs(a,stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

I used CodeBlocks 17.12 to compile this C program.
My OS is Windows 7 (32-bit)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf

Comment: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfinterlace.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

When you enter your answer, there is a newline char at the end (\n) in the buffer. When fgets() reads your input it reads the newline to. You can remove the newline, or use a regex to skip it, or fgets() once on the line so that you can use scanf() once more as suggested in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5918091/5815788) that may help you.

And, please, remember to search in stackoverflow before posting a question!