# Buffer related issues when we use fgets in loop

Tags: c, buffer, fgets, gets, puts

The code works fine in first iteration but in second iteration the player_name is not asking for input it jumps directly to second fgets.
And the puts prints a extra line space after it

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct cricket
{
char player_name[20];
char team_name[30];
float average;
}cricket;
void main()
{
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
{printf("Enter the detail of team %d\n",i);
printf("Enter the player name :");
fgets(cricket.player_name, 20, stdin);
printf("Enter the team name :");
fgets(cricket.team_name, 30, stdin);
printf("Enter the batting average of the player :");
scanf(" %f",&cricket.average);
puts(cricket.player_name);
puts(cricket.team_name);
printf("%f\n",cricket.average);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you indent your code?

Comment: And you need an array of `cricket[5]`, then `i` should from `0` to `<5`, then use `cricket[i]`

Comment: It is not "buffer related". What you can do is use `scanf(" ");` in the beginning of the loop.

Comment: @-e2-e4 can you plz help me the code because im not exactly getting what you are trying to say

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thank you sir for your ans but i had tried that also and it does the same thing

Comment: `scanf(" ")` with a space in there, just before the first `fgets`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala can you tell me the reason  why to do so

Comment: @AyushSrivastav did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf