# the frequency of a character in C (issue when I read the character)

Tags: c, string, function

So I need to write a function which counts the frequency of a character in a string in C. The function parameters must be just the character I want to count. So here's my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int charFrequency(char c) {
    char str[500];
    int i, nr = 0;
    printf("Enter the string: ");
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    for(i=0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {
        if (str[i] == c) {
            nr++;
        }
    }
    return nr;
}


int main(void) {
    char c;
    int nr;
    printf("Enter the character you want to count: ");
    c = getc(stdin);
    getc(stdin); // what is the role of this code line? if I delete this line the programs does not work anymore.
    nr = charFrequency(c);
    printf("The frequency is %d", nr);
    return 0;
}
```

I have a problem when I read the character I want to count. I use getc but the program doesn't work fine. But if I write again `getc(stdin)` the program works fine.

I also tried with scanf but I have the same issue. Can someone explain me how `getc` works?

Comment: You type 'F', 'ENTER', 'THE STRING', 'ENTER'... your `getc()` deals with the 'F', your second `getc()` deals with the 'ENTER' and the `fgets()` inside the function deals with 'THE STRING' and the last 'ENTER'; if you omit the 2nd `getc()`, the `fgets()` deals with the 'ENTER' after the 'F'

Comment: Similar to: [fgets doesn't work after scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf), and [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer). It is best not to mix your input methods. You can get the character to match by using `fgets()` and taking the input string's first character.

Comment: the function: `getc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`

Comment: the second call to `getc()` is to consume the trailing '\n'

Comment: OT: regarding; `for(i=0; i<strlen(str); ++i) {`  This calls the function: `strlen()` for each character in the user entered string.  Rather wasteful of resources.  Suggest:  `for(i=0; str[i]; ++i) {` which will exit the loop when the string terminator NUL character is encountered

Comment: what happens if the user enters a EOF or only a '\n' for either of those inputs?  Therefore, the code should be checking the result of the first call to `getc()` and the result of `fgets()`

Comment: _Side note:_ Don't put `strlen` in the condition expression in a `for` loop. It slows down the running time from O(n) to O(n^2) (e.g.) if length of the string was 1000, instead of scanning the string _once_ for a total of 1000 bytes fetched, it will scan the string 1000 times--1000*1000 bytes. Or, 1,000,000 bytes will be fetched. Do this: `size_t len = strlen(str); for (i=0; i<len; ++i)`

Comment: Or, better yet, do: `for (int t = *str++;  t != 0;  t = *str++) { if (t == c) nr++; }`