# The print statements in the while statement are printed out more than the desired number of times

Tags: c, struct, while-loop

SOURCE ::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h> // strcmp()

#define MAX 255

struct book {
    int Book_ID;
    char* Title;
    char* Publisher;
    char* Author;
    int Price;
} book_db;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    char cBuf[MAX];  
    int fd, id;
    char c;
   
    if (argc < 2) {      
    fprintf(stderr, "manual : %s file_name\n", argv[0]);  
    }
    if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0640)) == -1) {     
    perror(argv[1]);   
    }    
    
    while(1) {    
    int number; 
    printf("\nThis is Seong-Jae Database Book Management System\n");    
    printf("1. Add book\n");    
    printf("2. Update book\n"); 
    printf("3. Find book\n");   
    printf("4. Exit\n");      
    printf(">> ");   
    fgets(cBuf, MAX, stdin);    
   
    if(strncmp(cBuf, "1", 1) == 0){ 
            printf("%-9s %-15s %-15s %-10s %-10s\n", "Book_ID","Title", "Publisher", "Author", "Price");
            scanf("%d %s %s %s %d", &book_db.Book_ID, book_db.Title, book_db.Publisher, book_db.Author, &book_db.Price) == 5;
            lseek(fd, book_db.Book_ID * sizeof(book_db), SEEK_SET);
            write(fd, (char *) &book_db, sizeof(book_db));
    } // case1 END
    else if(strncmp(cBuf, "4", 1) == 0){        
        break;
    }
    } // while
} // main
```

OUTPUT::

```
*@ubuntu:~/myshell/pl02$ gcc -o db_manage db_mng.c 
*@ubuntu:~/myshell/pl02$ ./db_manage db_test.db

This is Database Book Management System
1. Add book
2. Update book
3. Find book
4. Exit
>> 1
Book_ID   Title           Publisher       Author     Price     
1         unix            shell           sj         13000

This is Database Book Management System
1. Add book
2. Update book
3. Find book
4. Exit
>> 
This is Database Book Management System
1. Add book
2. Update book
3. Find book
4. Exit
>>
```

The result I thought is that `printf` statements are executed in the while statement, and when they meet `fgets` and receive input while waiting for input, the conditional statement according to the input is executed.

However, the result value is input to `fgets`, the result corresponding to the if statement "1" is executed, and the `printf` statement is executed twice more.

How to solve this?

Desired result ::
ex)

```
Book_ID Title Publishr author price
1              unix shell        sj         13000

This is Seong-Jae Database Book Management System
1. Add book
2. Update book
3. Find book
4. Exit
>>
```

It makes the above wait state and executes the function when another value is entered later.

+) Currently, functions 2 and 3 have not been implemented, so only functions 1 and 4 are included.

Comment: Please explain your idea of the `== 5;`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Please see [fgets() doesn't work after scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf). The `scanf()` leavs a newline in the input buffer. This is read as an "empty" string by the next `fgets()` (it contains only a newline).

Comment: Translated Korean to: *How do I get `fgets` to run after `scanf` or where can I fix it?* By reading all the inputs with `fgets()` and applying `sscanf()` to the input string, instead of applying `scanf()` to `stdin`.

Comment: @Weather Vane Note: I modified the code. There is a part to be edited, so I deleted the comment and wrote it again, but you already posted it. Thank you.
However, I have difficulty in translating when using Google Translator because I am not proficient in English. I would really appreciate it if you could write it in sentences.
ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ Why does the @ function not work..?
Yunnosch -->  'book_id title publish author price' I specified ==5 to accept 5 inputs.
Also, the desired results have been added to the text.

Comment: You should read all input with fgets. Then apply sscanf to the string.

Comment: So you will input to `mystring` with `fgets` and then `if(sscanf(mystring, "%d %s %s %s %d", ...) != 5) { /* error */ }`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help... It worked out well. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a definitive `break;` behind an `if`-block and **not** `else if`-block, which is "calculated" each iteration,

Like:

```
while(1){
/* your code */
if(/* condition is no longer true */) break;
}
```