# How do you rename a file in c

Tags: c

How do I got about renaming a file the file is called "Patient.txt" and i wish for it to be called whatever value is stored in the string "surname" after the string combine. I know my code is also riddled with small errors and bad practises which I will try and amend however im looking to fix the FILE name problem.

```
FILE*fopenFile(char fileName[], char fileMode[])
{
     int height, weight;
     char name[25], issues[30], curMeds[30], surname[25], birthDay[6];
     FILE *fbor = fopen(fileName, fileMode); 
     if(!fbor)
     {
        puts("Unable to open File");
        exit(1);
     }
     printf("Enter First name: ");
     scanf("%s", name);  
     printf("Enter Surname: ");
     scanf("%s", surname);  
     printf("Enter your DoB (ddmmyy): ");
     scanf("%s", birthDay);
     printf("Enter weight (Kg): ");
     scanf("%d", &weight);
     printf("Enter Height in CM: ");
     scanf("%d", &height);
     printf("Enter Medical Issues: ");
     fgets(issues, 30, stdin);
     emptyBuffer();
     printf("Enter Current Medication: ");
     fgets(curMeds, 30, stdin);
     
     fprintf(fbor, "First Name: %s\n", &name[25]);
     fprintf(fbor, "Surname: %s\n", &surname[25]);
     fprintf(fbor, "DoB: %s\nHeight: %d\n", &birthDay[6], height);
     fprintf(fbor, "Weight: %d\n", weight);
     fprintf(fbor, "Medical issues: ");
     fprintf(fbor, issues);
     fprintf(fbor, "Current medication: ");
     fprintf(fbor, curMeds);
     fclose(fbor);
     
     char fileType[] = ".mxa";
     
     strncat(surname, birthDay, 6);
     strncat(surname, fileType, 4);
     
     printf("\n  ..............................");
     printf("\n   File Saved as %s", surname);
     printf("\n  ..............................\n\n\n");
     
     if (rename(fileName, surname) == 0)
     {
        printf("File renamed successfully.\n");
     }
     else
     {
        printf("rename file failed.\n");
     }
     exit(0);
     
     return 0;
}
```

The files Name is not changing.

Comment: The number of incorrect string arguments to both `scanf` and `fprintf` in this code outnumber the correct ones; byt a *lot*.  Just look at the first two `scanf` calls. One of those is (almost) correct. I.e. `rename` is the least of your worries right now.

Comment: Why do you have a second `printf("%s\n", fileName);` after the call to `rename`? Do you expect it to print something else than the first `printf("%s\n", fileName);`? BTW your code is indented correctly...

Comment: All the code is running correctly though when run , just the file is being saved as the original name.

Comment: Please see [fgets() doesn't work after scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf), and [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)

Comment: yeah the second printf("%s\n", fileName); is a test to see if the file has renamed.

Comment: `rename` will rename the _file_, but it won't magically change the content of `fileName`. BTW `rename` may fail and you don't check this. Read the [documentation of rename](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rename/) closely

Comment: `&name[25]` etc are very wrong. That's the address of the next character *past* the buffer. The undefined behaviours may have corrupted `FILE *fbor` which has alreay been assigned.

Comment: I'll amend the bad practices once i've figured this out. I've never actually programed before and this is my first assignment. I fclosed(fbor) below the last fprintf and its still not renaming and is coming up with the error used from the code solution above

Comment: If you call rename() two times in a row with the same arguments, be sure the second time will fail, unless oldname==newname (which should fail anyway? Never tried that!)...

Comment: oh wow your're right. what a melt I am haha ill change that now , thankyou!

Comment: still not changing the file name.

Answer (score 2):

Function call:

```
int rename(const char * oldname, const char * newname);
```

program :
Program to rename a file using rename() function

```
/**
 * C program to rename a file using rename() function.
 */

#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    // Path to old and new files
    char oldName[100], newName[100];

    // Input old and new file name
    printf("Enter old file path: ");
    scanf("%s", oldName);

    printf("Enter new file path: ");
    scanf("%s", newName);


    // rename old file with new name
    if (rename(oldName, newName) == 0)
    {
        printf("File renamed successfully.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Unable to rename files. Please check files exist and you have permissions to modify files.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Source](https://codeforwin.org/2018/03/c-program-rename-a-file-using-rename-function.html)

Answer (score 1):

You must close the file before you are able to rename it, with the function `rename`. This seems to be your main issue within the question asked. Also, the arguments of "rename" function should be "const char*", which is not the case of the variables you are passing.

Note: There aresmall mistakes and bad practices on this core snipped, but since the question is not about it, I`m not commenting about it.

Comment: *You must close the file before you are able to rename it, with the function `rename`.*  That's basically a Windows-only restriction.  POSIX systems in general not only allow a file to be renamed at any time, they even allow it to be deleted while open.  It's a ***very*** useful paradigm.

Comment: I'll amend the bad practices once i've figured this out. I've never actually programed before and this is my first assignment. I fclosed(fbor) below the last fprintf and its still not renaming and is coming up with the error used from the code solution above.

Comment: "...the arguments of "rename" function should be "const char*", which is not the case of the variables you are passing" - that is not correct. `const char *` guarantees that **the rename function** will not use the pointer to whatever is pointed at. OP can pass an unqualified `char *` to `rename` and it will work Just Fine.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica: Pass a pointer to a const-qualified type suggests that the called function will not modify the pointed-to object(s) through that pointer. It does not guarantee it. Because `const` was grafted onto C late in its development, there are situations where it is necessarily removed by a called function, and this is permitted and defined by the C standard if the pointed-to object was not originally defined with `const`.