# fgets() is not getting input

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

fgets() is skipping and not taking input. How can I solve it? I've tried using a scanf(), but scanf() is taking input upto the first space. I want to take a input such as: Steve Jobs

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    // ints
    int age;
    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("You are %d \n", age);

    // chars
    char grade;
    printf("Enter your grade: ");
    scanf(" %c", &grade);
    printf("You got an %c on the test \n", grade);

    // doubles
    double gpa;
    printf("Enter your gpa: ");
    scanf("%lf", &gpa);
    printf("Your gpa is %lf \n", gpa);

    // strings
    char name[20];
    printf("Enter your name:");
    fgets( name, 20, stdin);  // this line is not working
    printf("Hello %s! \n", name);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not mix `fgets()` with `scanf()` and vice-versa.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fgets doesn't work after scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf)

Comment: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: Use `fgets()` only for clean input.  Use `scanf()` to continue having problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this:

```
scanf("%lf", &gpa);
```

left a newline `\n` in stdin

this:

fgets( name, 20, stdin);

stops inputting after consuming the newline `\n`

You might want to learn about character sets, similar to:

```
scanf( "%19[^\n]", name );
```

or simply calling: `getchar()` before calling `fgets()`

Comment: using scanf("%19[^\n]", name);   is not working..

Comment: sorry, there should be a space before the character set, as in: `" %[^\n]"`  The leading space consumes any leading `white space` like the newline