# Can somebody explain why the line of this code containing fgets isn't getting executed?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        int num;
        char answer[10];
        char affirmation[10]="yes";
        do
        {
                printf("Enter a number : \n");
                scanf("%d",&num);
                if (num % 97 == 0)
                {
                        printf("No. is divisible by 97!\n");
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("No. is not divisible by 97!\n");
                }

                printf("Once More ? [yes/no] \n");
                fgets(answer,sizeof(answer),stdin);
        }
        while(strcmp(affirmation,answer) == 0);
        return 0;
}
```

I expected from this program to check the divisibility of a provided number by 97 and then to ask if I again want it to check for another number if I input "yes". But it isn't prompting for my input .
If anybody can explain the reason behind this problem and suggest some ways to get through, it will be appreciated.The output is given below:
[This output is for num = 194.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK737.jpg)

Comment: Because you can't mix `scanf` and `fgets`.  Try using `scanf("%9s", answer)` to read the y/n response.  (Actually, I'm exaggerating: you *can* mix them, but you have to worry about several rather crazy, esoteric details.)

Comment: `scanf("%d",&num);` leaves the `<ENTER>` in the input buffer. That `<ENTER>` is the only thing `fgets()` catches.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fgets doesn't work after scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf)

Answer (score 0):

It *is* being executed but what it's reading is the newline character in the input stream that *wasn't* read when you did the `scanf`.

What your `scanf` does is to first skip any white space, then read an integer up to but not including the first non-digit character, which is probably the `\n` generated by the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

Then, because `fgets` reads a line up to the next newline, you get an empty line.

In both the preceding two paragraphs, I'm assuming for simplicity ideal conditions such as ensuring it's a valid integer and that the line is not longer than the size you provided. Obviously, deviating from that could cause unruly behaviour.

It's generally not a good idea to mix the two input types unless you know in great detail what will be in the input stream. It's often better to *just* use line-based input and then `sscanf` that into more appropriate variables.

That way, you can be more sure about where your input stream is at any given point.

A *quick* fix in this particular case is simply to augment your `scanf` so that it skips to the start of the next line:

```c
scanf("%d",&num);
while (getchar() != '\n') {}
```

---

The other problem you'll have after that is the fact that your `fgets` input will actually be `"yes\n"` rather than `"yes"`, so that string comparison won't work.

If you're after a fairly robust line input function that takes care of that (and many other things), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-do-i-read-a-string-entered-by-the-user-in-c/4023921#4023921).