# For some reason skipping the entire gets section of the code

Tags: c

What I'm trying to do is to replace a specific line within a txt file using C but for some reason after saying what line i want to change it just ended the exe.

```
void UpdateCustomerPortfolio()
{
    const char path[500] = "C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\College stuff\\Final assessment\\Fundimentals of programming\\Accounts\\";
    int Ic[12],line;
    char txt[5] =".txt",num[100];
    FILE * fPtr;
    FILE * fTemp;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char newline[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int count;
    
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("Input IC number: ");
    gets(Ic);
    
    strcat (path, Ic);
    strcat (path, txt);
    
    
    system("cls");
    
    printf("Enter the Information that requires an update:");
    printf("\n[01]First Name");
    printf("\n[02]Last Name");
    printf("\n[04]Home Address");
    printf("\n[05]Contact Number");
    printf("\n[06]Email Address\n");
    scanf("%d ",line);
```

This is the part for some reason it keeps ending after the user enters the line they want to change. I did try using fflush(stdin); here again but it still didn't work.

```
    printf("Replace '%d' line with: ", line);
    fgets(newline, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);


    /*  Open all required files */
    fPtr  = fopen(path, "r");
    fTemp = fopen("replace.tmp", "w"); 

    /* fopen() return NULL if unable to open file in given mode. */
    if (fPtr == NULL || fTemp == NULL)
    {
        /* Unable to open file hence exit */
        printf("\nUnable to open file.\n");
        printf("Please check whether file exists and you have read/write privilege.\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }


    /*
     * Read line from source file and write to destination 
     * file after replacing given line.
     */
    count = 0;
    while ((fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fPtr)) != NULL)
    {
        count++;

        /* If current line is line to replace */
        if (count == line)
            fputs(newline, fTemp);
        else
            fputs(buffer, fTemp);
    }


    /* Close all files to release resource */
    fclose(fPtr);
    fclose(fTemp);

    /* Delete original source file */
    remove(path);

    /* Rename temporary file as original file */
    rename("replace.tmp", path);

    printf("\nSuccessfully replaced '%d' line with '%s'.", line, newline);
}
```

Comment: Don't mix the input methods, they don't behave the same with newlines. See [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer). And stop using `gets()` which is obsolete and is no longer part of the standard C library.

Comment: Also please see [fgets() doesn't work after scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf).

Comment: Also note that [`fflush(stdin)` is a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).

Comment: You asked almost identical question yesterday. It was closed because of the lack of information. Do not ask new question only edit the new one.. Do not abuse the saystem

Answer (score -1):

Your scanf should read `scanf("%d", &line);`