# Why doesn't fgets get the first input?

Tags: c, string, function, dynamic, fgets

I am creating a few dynamic strings, using a function that uses fgets for getting input from the user. But the first time when I am trying to get the name of the airport, it's just "skip" the fgets automatically put `\n` in `temp` and continue the function. all the other inputs are right instead of the first one.

```
Please enter name of Airport:
```

Here it's just skipping the input process and straight printing "enter the address":

```
----------Please enter the address-------------

Please enter name of country:

Please enter name of city:
```

```
int initAirport(Airport* airportP)
{
    airportP->nameOfAirPort = createDynamicString("Please enter name of Airport:\n");
    printf("----------Please enter address-------------\n");
    airportP->country = createDynamicString("Please enter name of country:\n");
    airportP->city = createDynamicString("Please enter name of city:\n");
    airportP->address = createDynamicString(" Please enter name of Address:\n");
    printf("Please enter house number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&(airportP->houseNumber));
    return 1;
}
```

```
char* createDynamicString(const char* msg)
{
    char* str;
    char temp[254];
    printf(msg);
    fgets(temp,254,stdin);
    str = (char*)malloc((strlen(temp)+1) * sizeof(char));
    if (!str)
        return NULL;
    strcpy(str, temp);
    //str[strlen(str) - 1] = 0;
    return str;
}
```

```
#pragma once
#define MAX 254

typedef struct
{
    char* nameOfAirPort;
    char* country;
    char* city;
    char* address;
    int houseNumber;

} Airport;

int initAirport(Airport* pNameOfAirport);
void addNumberSignToString(char* stringOfNumberSign);
void printNameOfAirport(const Airport* pNameOfAirport);
int isSameAirport(Airport* airport1P, Airport* airport2P);
int isAirportName(Airport* airportP, char* airportName);
void freeAirport(Airport* airportP);
```

Comment: Can you provide the Airport struct?

Comment: Thanks for let me know, just add that

Comment: Is there some kind of Input reading before calling initAirport?
Some scanf or getchar?

Comment: Yes there is scanf that asks the user if he wanna add an airport then call another function that calls to initairport (but this is the last input reading from the user).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` leaves the newline character in the buffer after which `fgets()` picks it up and quits before the user has a chance to input anything.

You'll have to clear the buffer after `scanf()`

```c
void clearInputBuffer(void)
{
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this problem: [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

After you use `scanf()` function, `scanf()` leaves a newline character `\n` in your buffer. Then after, the fgets() in your `initAirport` function appears, it takes that newline character and you can't enter input. But that happens only once, since the next time you call `createDynamicString` function, you use `fgets()` function, instead of `scanf()`.

You can enter this sample of code just after your first call of `scanf()` function, the one you have said exists and asks the user if he wanna add an airport then call another function that calls to `initAirport()`:

```
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

This basically takes existing letters in your buffer until it hits newline character. In this case this will filter out the newline character that `scanf()` left in the buffer.

Comment: This could be an infinite loop. ```getchar()``` can return EOF if the input buffer overflows, in which case, there is no newline.