# Making a mad libs game

Tags: c, error-handling

I am trying to make a mad libs game but every time I test the first two `scanf` functions work, but the `fgets` function is not working how it should be.
it keeps printing the same things I want it to  but it's showing the mad libs text before the user has a chance to type in the `fgets` input

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

  char color[20];

  char COL2[20];

  printf("Enter a color: ");

  scanf("%s", color);

  printf("Enter a another color: ");

  scanf("%s", COL2);

  printf("Enter a celebrity name: \n");

  char celebrity[15];

  fgets(celebrity, 15, stdin);

  printf("Roses are %s", color);

  printf("Violets are %s", COL2);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fgets doesn't work after scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf)

Comment: Show the exact input you provide and the resulting output. Also provide the exact output you want it to return.

Comment: By the way, what does "mad libs" mean?

Comment: @kaylum https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Libs

Answer (score 0):

```
fscanf(stdin, "%15s", celebrity);
```

It worked on my laptop, so it should be fine.
Also fscanf is better and safer usually from what I've heard. Because it checks for end of line.