# How to use correctly tridimensional arrays to save and print strings?

Tags: c

I have to save three different strings in n number of 2D arrays, for that reason I created a 3D array named datosCliente[size][4][size]. After that I have to print their content. But when I'm printing the strings in the first and second string the first character disappear, and the third string isn't printed.

> The first string is the name of a country.
> The second is the date of departure.
> The last is the date of return.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int size = 100;

void ingresoDatos(char [size][4][size], int*);
void imprimirDatos(char [size][4][size], int*);

int main(void) {
  char  datosCliente[size][4][size];
  int cant;
  FILE *document;
  document = fopen("data.txt", "a");
  if(document == NULL) {
    printf("Error al abrir el archivo.\n");
  }else {
    ingresoDatos(datosCliente, &cant);
    imprimirDatos(datosCliente, &cant);
  }
  fclose(document);
  return 0;
}

void ingresoDatos(char datos[size][4][size], int *cant) {
  int tam = 0;
  system("clear");
  printf("Ingreso de datos\n");
  do {
    printf("Ingrese el número de clientes: ");
    scanf("%d", &tam);
  }while(tam >= 100 || tam <= 0);
  *cant = tam;
  for(int i = 1; i <= tam; i++) {
    system("clear");
    printf("Ingrese el destino: ");
    fgets(&datos[i][0][0], 20, stdin);
    getchar();
    printf("Ingrese la fecha de salida: ");
    fgets(&datos[i][1][0], 30, stdin);
    getchar();
    printf("Ingrese la fecha regreso: ");
    fgets(&datos[i][2][0], 30, stdin);
    getchar();
  }
}
void imprimirDatos(char datos[size][4][size], int *cant) {
  system("clear");
  for(int i = 1; i <= *cant; i++) {
    printf("Cliente %d:\n", i+1);
    printf("Destino: %s", &datos[i][0][100]);
    printf("Fecha de salida: %s", &datos[i][1][100]);
    printf("Fecha de regreso: %s", &datos[i][2][100]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

I enter this data:

```
tam: 1
Destino (to): China
Fecha de salida (depart in): 23 de septiembre de 2022
Fecha de regreso (return in): 24 de noviembre de 2022
```

And this is the output:

```
Cliente 1:
Destino: hina
Fecha de salida: 3 de septiembre de 2022
Fecha de regreso:
```

I had forgotten mention but I'm using Replit to do the code.

Answer (score 1):

- `scanf("%d", &tam);` doesn't consume a newline character even if it is entered. ([c - fgets doesn't work after scanf - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf)) In my opinion, you shouldn't mix `scanf()` and `fgets()`. You can use `fgets()` to read a line and `sscanf()` to parse the line.
- `fgets()` consumes a newline character (if it is entered). Calling `getchar();` after that will drop the first character of the next line.

Considering these points, the function `ingresoDatos` should be:

```c
void ingresoDatos(char datos[size][4][size], int *cant) {
  int tam = 0;
  system("clear");
  printf("Ingreso de datos\n");
  do {
    char buffer[100];
    printf("Ingrese el número de clientes: ");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    sscanf(buffer, "%d", &tam);
  }while(tam >= 100 || tam <= 0);
  *cant = tam;
  for(int i = 1; i <= tam; i++) {
    system("clear");
    printf("Ingrese el destino: ");
    fgets(&datos[i][0][0], 20, stdin);
    printf("Ingrese la fecha de salida: ");
    fgets(&datos[i][1][0], 30, stdin);
    printf("Ingrese la fecha regreso: ");
    fgets(&datos[i][2][0], 30, stdin);
  }
}
```

Comment: Additionally the output statements using like `&datos[i][0][100]` are incorrect and should be `datos[i][0]`