# How to set fgets() length at runtime (in C)

Tags: c, fgets

I am new to the C language.

I want to determine the **fgets()** length at runtime, something like:

```
int i;
char str[100];
scanf("%d",&i);    
fgets(str, i, stdin);
```

At execution, the program just skips my fgets() line, there is no error; I don't see anything in dbg.

If I set a concrete value for the input length, it works fine.

```
fgets(str, 10, stdin);
```

Could somebody please help me understand what is happening? According to [this C Reference](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) the second argument is a simple int.

This is the full example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int i;
   char str[100];

   puts("Enter a number: ");
   scanf("%d", &i);
   fgets(str, i, stdin);
   printf("String contents: %s", str);
   return 0;
}
```

Vs. hard-coded value which is working fine:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

```
int main() {
 
   char str[100];

   fgets(str, 10, stdin);
   printf("String contents: %s", str);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including both an example of where `fgets(str, i, stdin);` does not work and an example of where `fgets(str, 10, stdin);` does work with code that is otherwise the same.

Comment: Please see [fgets() doesn't work after scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf).

Comment: maybe `i` is invalid? try to debug it

Comment: @EricPostpischil my crystal ball says that using a "concrete value" means getting rid of the `scanf` altogether, thus eliminating the issue mentioned in the link.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Why not? For a concrete value, no `scanf` is needed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Full example added.

Comment: You have not added the full code for the second example where the buffer size is hard coded.

Comment: We still like to know what you see as output for `str`, if you think that `fgets()` is skipped. You would like to output the length of the received input as well.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: Yes, that would explain it.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry, my bad, the working hard-coded example added.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp 100 points, you have a good crystal ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `scanf`, you solicit the user to enter a line of text. `scanf("%d", &i);` consumes the numeral the user enters in that line but leaves the new-line character in the buffer. The later `fgets` reads that new-line character, and that causes it not to read any further, so you get an empty line from `fgets`. Use `getchar()` after your call to `scanf()` to consume the new-line character:

```
int i;
char str[100];
scanf("%d",&i);
getchar();

fgets(str, i, stdin);
```

Or, more thoroughly, after `scanf`, consume the entire rest of the line up to the new-line character, in case the user entered other text:

```
int i;
char str[100];
scanf("%d",&i);
while (getchar() != '\n')
    ;

fgets(str, i, stdin);
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually works. But I don't understand why...

Comment: @marco-a Thank you, it now makes perfect sense.

Comment: `while (getchar() != '\n')     ;` leads to an infinite loop on end-of-file.