# I don't know why it would not function as it should be, I used gets() and fgets(), the same result happen

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student{
    char name[20];
    char studentNumber[5];
    int yearOfBirth;
    float avgPoint;
};

int main(){
    struct student hssv[3];
    int i;
//input info for students, this case its 3 students
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf("Input element value: ");
        printf("\nInput your name: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(hssv[i].name, sizeof(hssv[i].name), stdin); //this line doesnt work for the loop
        printf("Input your student code: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(hssv[i].studentNumber, sizeof(hssv[i].studentNumber), stdin);
        printf("Input your year of birth: ");
        scanf("%d", &hssv[i].yearOfBirth);
        printf("Input your point: ");
        scanf("%f", &hssv[i].avgPoint);
    }
//output info
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf("\nOutput element value: ");
        printf("\nYour name: %s", hssv[i].name);
        printf("\nInput your student code: %s", hssv[i].studentNumber);
        printf("\nInput your year of birth: %d", hssv[i].yearOfBirth);
        printf("\n\nInput your point: %f", hssv[i].avgPoint);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why it would not function as it should be, I used get() but then there is a warning saying I should use fgets(). Then I looked it up, and used it but the same result keep happening.
The input for name does not work for 2nd onward in the loop, I guess it's buffer overflow ? but Im using fflush() already. Please help...

Comment: `gets()` is unsafe to `fgets()` is the way to go.  Please revise question and explain what the problem is.

Comment: [do not `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin), it is undefined behavior

Comment: as for your problem, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918079/fgets-doesnt-work-after-scanf) and its duplicates should help

Comment: @AllanWind: I've taken the general opinion that that is an overfit question. The fact we can make scanf work doesn't mean we should.

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714). `gets` has been removed from the C standard long ago

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `gets()`. It's been withdrawn.

`fgets()` will stop at the end of `hssv[i].name` (that's what the parameter taking `sizeof(hssv[i].name)` is for). `gets()` will keep going if the user types too much and trample on whatever comes after. Servers have been commandeered this way.

Your code isn't working because the `scanf()` call left a newline in the input buffer. There are ways to solve this; my recommendation is to never use `scanf` but only `sscanf` like so:

```
char linebuf[21]; // Reuse for all number reads
// ...
fgets(linebuf, sizeof(linebuf), stdin);
sscanf(linebuf, "%d", &hssv[i].yearOfBirth);
```

Get rid of `fflush(stdin);`; it doesn't always work.

Note to mod: while we normally delete thank you comments; in this case trying to do so would make the comment thread make no sense.

Comment: I've been using fgets(), but the result stays the same. Do you have any recommendations ?

Comment: @tdm2k: if you comment out your scanf lines you will be able to observe that it's not fgets that isn't working.

Comment: Thank you very much !! Its working great !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to call fflush(stdin). In general, fflush() is not particularly useful for input streams. It has fairly odd application for input files where seek() is usable, and is mostly used for output streams (Send the buffered data out).

I notice you're not checking the return value from fgets() and you don't mention what you get instead of the expected result. I'll also note that in your current configuration, you're allowing up to 19 characters in the name.  Is that the intended value? (fgets() needs one character for the terminating null). Also, it's likely the use of scanf() to read the last element in the previous iteration of the loop not consuming the newline. fgets() will consume the newline and I highly recommend using fgets() to read into a buffer and then sscanf() to parse that buffer in order to avoid such unnecessary (and unpleasant) surprises.

Try commenting with details on what is happening instead of what you expect (more than "it doesn't work")... Is it returning NULL? Does part of the string get passed and the rest truncated? What exactly is happening?

Try removing the fflush() as well, that may well be part of your problem as it might be dumping the input buffer that the user typed before trying to read it.

Comment: I'm very new to this so there's some missing info in my explanation. Thank you for your advice! I will note that for next question.

Comment: That's an awfully soft step with regard to `fflush()`.  The language spec is much more firm: "If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined**" (emphasis added).  As far as the spec is concerned, `fflush` is *only* for flushing output.

Comment: Then MS screws it all up by explicitly making `fflush(stdin)` conforming behavior... Go with the standard...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin MSVC did at one time, but not since several years. Their doc on [fflush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fflush?view=msvc-170) says *"If the stream was opened in read mode, or if the stream has no buffer, the call to fflush has no effect, and any buffer is retained."*

Comment: Yep, VS2017 was still touting `fflush(stdin)` while now VS2022 has cleaned it up -- thank God. I can't tell you how many pendants pointed out it wasn't UB because...